# jquery .on(change) on specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

EDIT: Sorry I was very tired and the code was actually working when writing here! WTF :D

I have many different dropdowns on the same page and wan't to do an AJAX request when on of them changes.

If I do it this way, it works:

```
  $(document).on('change', '#changeresponsibleuser', function(){
    var user = $(this).val();
    var partnerid = $(this).attr('name');
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "resources/dialogs/editResponsibleUser.php",
              data: {user: user,
                     partnerid: partnerid},
              success: function(msg){
                    $('.productmessage').html(msg).hide().fadeIn(500).fadeOut(4000);

                  },
                });
  });
```

But this trickers on all dropdown boxes I have on the page. I wan't to do something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#changeresponsibleuser").on('change',function(){
    var user = $(this).val();
    var partnerid = $(this).attr('name');
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "resources/dialogs/editResponsibleUser.php",
              data: {user: user,
                     partnerid: partnerid},
              success: function(msg){
                    $('.productmessage').html(msg).hide().fadeIn(500).fadeOut(4000);

                  },
                });

      });
  });
```

So it ONLY listens to the dropdown with that exact ID. But it does not work, the on change event is not triggered.

How can I trigger the event only when  #changeresponsibleuser changes?

The markup looks like this:

```
<select id="changeresponsibleuser" name="2" class="responsible2 form-control form-group">

<option name="user" value="36" selected="selected">One user</option>
<option name="user" value="41">Another user</option>
<option name="user" value="40">yet another user</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: __ID attributes in a document must be unique!__

Comment: after page load  `$("#changeresponsibleuser")` check this command in console to see the number of element in DOM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
 $("#changeresponsibleuser").on('change', function(){
   alert("Works");
 })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="changeresponsibleuser" name="2" class="responsible2 form-control form-group">

<option name="user" value="36" selected="selected">One user</option>
<option name="user" value="41">Another user</option>
<option name="user" value="40">yet another user</option>
</select>
```

It works. How do you say it is not working?

> But this trickers on all dropdown boxes I have on the page

No. You have to use class name instead id. It seems you are using duplicate ids. So it is triggering on all select dropdowns which has duplicate id.

```
$(document).on('change', '.changeresponsibleuser',function(){
   alert("Works");
 });
```

It will trigger on all drop down changes which has class `changeresponsibleuser`

Comment: Does it qualify to be an answer ? You don't need to post an answer to say _IT IS WORKING!_

Comment: If the code works fine, it should be closed as `not reproducible`.

Comment: Event delegation will work for duplicate IDs as well as it reach for all descendants matching a selector.. Though it is not preferred way!

Comment: Thats strange.. or maybe its not working here because I write the markup to DOM after load?  The markup is made from another AJAX request

Comment: Its the only dropdown with that #changeresponsibleuser id.

Comment: @Bolli Then how do you say that `this trickers on all dropdown boxes I have on the page`

Comment: I dont get it either.
Maybe its the $(document).on that trickers it on all selectboxes? I will try make a fiddle.

Comment: Uh oh..  I found the error. It was working all along! Thanks for leading me on the right path. There was no error, simply me being very tired. Sorry!. I was confused because I got the wrong message, but I simply forgot to change the message text.

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading drop down with id `changeresponsibleuser` with AJAX? If you are doing that it means dropdown is not available for binding change event on document ready. Instead using this you can use - `select onchange="function_name()"`

and you can write your ajax request in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup:

```
<select id="changeresponsibleuser" name="2" class="responsible2 form-control form-group">
    <option name="user" value="36" selected="selected">One user</option>
    <option name="user" value="41">Another user</option>
    <option name="user" value="40">yet another user</option>
</select>
```

And your js like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#changeresponsibleuser").change(function() {
        // do your stuff
    });
});
```

Don't forget to include jQuery lib in your markup.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```