# How to change the inputs' onchange event by name or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a snippet of HTML which is the simple version of my site. The inputs name is related to the row index. So, I am wondering how to change the inputs' onchange event using the jQuery?

For each row, it has its own function related to the row index. For example, for tr index = 0, it has the function Test1(), for tr index = 1, it has the function Test2()...

Cannot simply using the input selector, because there are some other inputs in the page. Only the id and name for the input are unique.

```
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '0'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@0@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@0@1" ct="Field" onchange=" SaveControlState(event,'Text');">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '1'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@1@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@1@1" ct="Field" onchange=" SaveControlState(event,'Text');">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '2'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@2@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@2@1" ct="Field" onchange=" SaveControlState(event,'Text');">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '3'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@3@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@3@1" ct="Field" onchange=" SaveControlState(event,'Text');">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Well, maybe I should put my desired result here.

```
<script>Do something here, then change the onchange events to below.</script>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '0'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@0@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@0@1" ct="Field" onchange="Test1();">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '1'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@1@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@1@1" ct="Field" onchange="Test2();">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '2'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@2@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@2@1" ct="Field" onchange="Test3();">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr stampId = '1001' index = '3'>
    <td>
        <span>
        <input type="text" name="QuickOrderQty@6@3@1" id="QuickOrderQty@6@3@1" ct="Field" onchange="Test4();">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery .on(change) on specific ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685587/jquery-onchange-on-specific-id)

Comment: You can pass the index as paramater to a generic function

Comment: If you change the onchange function to take in the variable `this`, then the method will have a reference to the input that triggered the event, regardless of what it's name/id is, possibly reducing the need to have unique/duplicate functions by index.

Comment: _"For each row, it has its own function related to the row index. For example, for tr index = 0, it has the function Test1(), for tr index = 1, it has the function Test2()..."_ - that should probably be _one_ function, that based on the passed index `switch`es into the applicable branch ...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if any mistakes occurred. This is my first time answering questions. I am not even that experienced.

if I understood you correctly, you want to know the element that caused the event to trigger. You can use the word this

```
$("input").change(function(event) {
    var x = $(this).val();
    // x = the value of the input element that triggered the event.
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you shouldnt be using inline `onchange` event handlers. Also, if you wish to target multiple elements with the same behaviour use a shared class. If you do both those things this becomes trivial using jQuery's `index()` method:

```js
var functions = {
   Test1: function(){ console.log("TextBox1 changed") },
   Test2: function(){ console.log("TextBox2 changed") },
   Test3: function(){ console.log("TextBox3 changed") },
   Test4: function(){ console.log("TextBox4 changed") }
}

$(document).on('change','.myClass',function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    functions["Test" + index]();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myClass">
<input type="text" class="myClass">
<input type="text" class="myClass">
<input type="text" class="myClass">
```